# Python Open file not creating new file

Tags: python, file

When I tell python to create a new file and write in it, it tells me that the directory does not exist.

Ive tried multiple solutions, using "with open()" , changing around the 'w' to 'w+' and so on.

```
if not os.path.exists(os.getcwd()+'/bin'):
    os.makedirs(os.getcwd()+'/bin/json')

    with open(os.getcwd()+'/bin/misc/names.txt', 'w+') as file:
        file.write('Ie`v(Janrkov(Uqjc=uv(Nvk(AJD=SO(F]u?(>-(=>(AO]r(=`nh(Koeneo(O]ldena(O]i(Iuhao(UCej(ING')
```

The error message is as follows

```
Bens-Air:Drug Empire Ben$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 "/Users/Ben/Desktop/Code/Drug Empire/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Ben/Desktop/Code/Drug Empire/main.py", line 27, in <module>
    with open(os.getcwd()+'/bin/misc/names.txt', 'w+') as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/Ben/Desktop/Code/Drug Empire/bin/misc/names.txt'
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You are creating directory at `/bin/json` but creating the file at `/bin/misc` maybe this is creating the problem

Comment: Using `w` or `w+` the file will be created if not exists, but not the directory. The directory `/bin/misc/` doesn't exist apparently

Comment: You have a race condition: a third party could create the directory after you check for it but before you attempt to create it yourself. Just try to create it, and catch the exception if it already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating the folder `/bin/json` but writing in `/bin/misc`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little sanity check needed I see, yeah, like everyone has said, you're writing to the wrong directory, change the line

```
 with open(os.getcwd()+'/bin/misc/names.txt', 'w+') as file:
```

to

```
 with open(os.getcwd()+'/bin/json/names.txt', 'w+') as file:
```